# Linear independent vectors - whats wrong with my solution?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Find $t$ so that the following vectors are linear independent:

$(t,0,0), (1,t,t), (1,1,t)$

---

So i put based on the definition

$xt+y1+z1=0$

$x0+xt+z1=0$

$x0+yt+zt=0$

This results in

(1): $xt+y+z=0$

(2): $xt+z=0$

(3): $(y+z)t=0$

From (1) and (2) we have:

$xt+y-xt=0$  and  $y=0$

Therefor from (3)

$zt=0$

This means, that $z=0$  or  $t=0$

1 Case: $t\neq 0$

This means $z=0$  and  $xt=0$ which means $x=0$. So the vectors are linear dependent in this case.

2. Case: $t=0$

From (2) we have $xt=-z$  and $t=-z/x$ which means $z=0$. From (1) we conclude that $x$ can take any value.

This means $t=0$, $y,z=0$ and $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

---

Can I do this this way?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot do it that way. You need to consider linear combinations of those three vectors.

More precisely, you want to see for what values of $t$ the equality
$$
a(t,0,0)+b(1,t,t)+c(1,1,t)=(0,0,0)
$$
*implies* $a=b=c=0$.

The equality can be rewritten
$$
(at+b+c,bt+c,bt+ct)=(0,0,0)
$$
In particular, $c=-bt$, so $bt-bt^2=0$; also $at+b-bt=0$.

If $t=0$, we conclude $c=0$ and $b=0$, but $a$ can be nonzero, so the vectors are linearly dependent.

If $t=1$, we conclude $c=-b$ and $a=0$; choosing $a=0$, $b=1$ and $c=-1$ proves the vectors are linearly dependent.

If $t\ne0$ and $t\ne1$, then $b=0$, so also $c=0$ and $a=0$. Thus the vectors are linearly independent.

---

You can also prove the same by considering
$$
\det\begin{bmatrix}
t & 1 & 1 \\
0 & t & 1 \\
0 & t & t
\end{bmatrix}=
t\det\begin{bmatrix}
t & 1 \\
t & t
\end{bmatrix}=t(t^2-t)=t^2(t-1)
$$
that's nonzero if and only if $t\ne0$ and $t\ne1$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $u,v,w$  be your vectors.
the determinant is

$\Delta=det(u,v,w)=t(t^2-t)$

they are independent if

$\Delta\neq 0 $

$\iff t\neq0$ and $t\neq 1$.